# MVC5 unobtrusive validations not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, unobtrusive-validation

I am using entity framework with database first approach.

I have created separate class for validations.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(RoleMetaData))]
    public partial class Role
    {

    }

    class RoleMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter role name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and my html form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Role", FormMethod.Post, new {  @class = "submitform" }))
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class="form-control" })
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success width-150" value="Save" />
}
```

but html rendering to browser without any data-* attributes like:

```
<input class="form-control" id="Name" name="Name"  type="text" value="">
```

I am wondering why it is not rendering data-* attributes.

Please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out where the problem was, the namespace of my validation class is different from namespace where data entity exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ValidationMessageFor to render data-* attributes for unobstrusive-validation. Use ValidationMessageFor like below:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Role", FormMethod.Post, new {  @class = "submitform" }))
    {
     @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class="form-control" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success width-150" value="Save" />
    }
```

And make sure client side validation is enabled in web.config like below:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are already set to true. . also @Html.ValidationMessageFor only shows the message. but in my case validation attributes are not rendering.